# How does QUIC's multiplexing differ from that of HTTP/2 in detail

Tags: http2, network-protocols, multiplexing, quic, http3

if Traefik receives a request for a webpage that includes images and a audio and the configuration specifies different servers for the different content types, does Traefik open individual streams for the individual items that are send back to the client or does it multiplex the content over one stream? In nginx, there is no evidence that it opens multiple streams i.e. it appears to be a straight forward replacement of QUIC with one stream for TCP i.e. it uses the same multiplexing approach regardless. I don’t see any approach that implements individual streams in Traefik either; so, I’d assume that they took the same approach i.e. that they do not make use of multiple streams currently.

Many articles just say it improved http2's multiplexing, but what exactly is it?

Comment: The title doesn't match the body of the question. Are you asking about quic vs http/2 or about how traefik works? Here is an answer that explains how quic differs (and is more efficient) than http/2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653228/how-does-quic-multiplexing-differ-from-that-of-http-2

Comment: Hi i feel it's a bit vague in that question?  and regarding to the question body i mean i noticed nginx is not really using QUIC stream, which means it's not separate streams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does QUIC multiplexing differ from that of HTTP/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653228/how-does-quic-multiplexing-differ-from-that-of-http-2)

Comment: Not really, or can you explain that more clearly?

Comment: As HTTP is a request/response protocol, it is the client that determines whether multiple streams (on the same QUIC connection) are used or not (as response is returned on the same stream that contained the request). You say "there is no evidence", but what kind of evidence are you looking for? One can only tell what's happening on the QUC connection when having the keys to decrypt the traffic.